# Can you retrieve Azure DevOps Wikis with a DevOps artifact query?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops

I've been trying to retrieve Wiki URLs that are linked to a work item, and I've been able to retrieve the link between Work Item and Wiki Page. However, the link return is a VSTFS artifact link. Is it possible to retrieve the true URL with the query provided [at this page of REST documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/Artifact%20Uri%20Query/Query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), or does this only work for retrieving Work Items? I currently am receiving a TF400898 error when attempting with a TFS link similar to below.

```
vstfs:///Wiki/WikiPage/{vstfs identification string}
```

EDIT: Current Function

```
def getWikiURL(azureToken, parsedTFS):
  # parsedTFS[0] == Project ID, parsedTFS[1] == Wiki Repo ID, parsedTFS[2] == [page1, page2, page3]

   reqURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/" + str(parsedTFS[0]) + "/_apis/_wiki/wikis/" + str(parsedTFS[1]) + "/pages/"

for pageDef in parsedTFS[2]:
  reqURL = reqURL + "/" + pageDef

authorization = str(b64.b64encode(bytes(':'+azureToken, 'ascii')), 'ascii)

headers = {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Authorization' : 'Basic '+authorization
}

r = requests.get(url=reqURL, headers=headers)

strR = r.content.decode("utf-8-sig")
print(strR)
```

print(strR) writes b''  to the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Rest API: [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), we can get the related wiki url to this work item with request url:

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?$expand=Relations&api-version=6.0
```

From the response body, we can find the url of ArtifactLink looks like:

```
url": "vstfs:///Wiki/WikiPage/7e8XXXXXX3c79%2Ff2bb2XXXXXXe7431d5a61%2Fwiki1".
```

And then use this Rest API: [Artifact Uri Query - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/artifact%20uri%20query/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get linked work items to this wiki page.

To retrieve the true URL of VSTFS artifact link, please follow below steps. Please note that using PostMan to get the result. And using [PAT authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) with full accesses.

1. After researching, I find that in fact the VSTFS artifact link is formatted looks like:

```
vstfs:///Wiki/WikiPage/{project id}%2F{wiki repository id}%2F{wiki page name}
```

2. Use this request url:

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wiki repository id}/pages//{wiki page name}
```

Its response will tell you the wiki page’s id.

If you use nested pages (i.e. {parent page}/{sub page}), the request url is below:

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wiki repository id}/pages//{parent page}/{sub page}
```

3. Finally, the true url of wiki page looks like:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_wiki/wikis/{wiki repository id}/{wiki page id}/{wiki page name}
```

Similarly, if you use nested pages (i.e. {parent page}/{sub page}), the url is below:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_wiki/wikis/{wiki repository id}/{wiki page id}/{sub page}
```

Comment: I've finally gotten the chance to implement this. Are you aware of what needs to be done for nested pages (i.e. pageA/pageB/pageC)?

Comment: I've tried "/wikis/{wiki repository id}/pages//{parent page}/{sub page}" and "/wikis/{wiki repository id}/pages//{parent page}%2F{child page}" and have had no luck.

Comment: I have updated the answer regarding to your nested pages, please using PostMan to check the result.

Comment: Alright, my request URL currently looks like "https://dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_apis/_wiki/wikis/{Wiki Repo ID}/pages//{Parent Page}/{Child Page}/{GrandChild Page}". I am using a proper authorization header. I currently am receiving no response, what is wrong with my request URL?

Comment: {Parent Page}/{Child Page}/{GrandChild Page} in my side is wiki1/wiki2/wiki3. And then my Get request url is: ```https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{Wiki Repo ID}/pages//wiki1/wiki2/wiki3```, using type of Basic Auth in Postman and the password is PAT with full accesses.

Comment: That looks like the request string I have built, and I'm using the same headers I used to retrieve the Wiki TFS link. I've parsed the TFS string by "%2F". My only thought as to why it isn't working is due to spaces (%20) in the wiki page name. I'll add an edit with my function.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my wiki structure.
[image]
To get url to access to wiki3 page and use your function, below script should work as expected. Please run the command: `$ pip install requests` if you haven't installed the `requests` library.

```
import base64 as b64
import requests
def getWikiURL(azureToken, parsedTFS):
    #azureToken == PAT, parsedTFS[0] == Project ID, parsedTFS[1] == Wiki Repo ID, parsedTFS[2] == ["wiki1","wiki2","wiki3"]

    reqURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/" + str(parsedTFS[0]) + "/_apis/wiki/wikis/" + str(parsedTFS[1]) + "/pages/"

    for pageDef in parsedTFS[2]:
        reqURL = reqURL + "/" + pageDef
    authorization = str(b64.b64encode(bytes(':'+azureToken, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : 'Basic '+authorization
    }

    r = requests.get(url=reqURL, headers=headers)
    strR = r.content.decode("utf-8-sig")
    print(strR)

getWikiURL("azureToken",["Project ID", "Wiki Repo ID", ["wiki1","wiki2","wiki3"]])
```

Comment: I've marked your previous answer as a solution, considering the code snippet here is not significantly different than my own, I must be messing something up elsewhere. I still get an empty response, but I must have a problem elsewhere. Thanks for all the help!